# Push Notification image is not showing for the first time while push in php

Tags: php, android, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Push notification with the image is not showing for the first notification. But after the subsequence notification, the image with text is showing in the Android app.

I have added the notification receiving code in the Android app. I have attached the PHP page for push notification.

```
$deviceToken = devicetoken;
$mob_type = 'Android';

if($mob_type=='Android'){
    $apiKey="androidapikey";
    }
    else {
        $apiKey="iosapikey";
    }


$message = [
    'to' => $deviceToken,
    'notification' => [
        'title' => 'test',
        'body' => 'Notification with image',
        'picture' => 'https://domain name/test_img.png',
    ],
];

$headers = [
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Handle the result as needed
echo $result;
```

Kindly give some solution. I have done all the solution from the chatgpt. Anyother solution?

Comment: Please attach android code as well and for now you can check that you are downloading image when you receive notification